# Economical route and fuel scooping

Tags: elite-dangerous

Does economical route algorithm take into account possibility to fuel scoop from stars along the way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both routing algorithms ignore fuel scooping for the initial route plan because of how the planning algorithm works...

Economic routing determines the routes that gives the shortest jumps, which means you less less fuel per jump, but you jump more.

Fastest routing determines jumps based on your maximum jump distance, and jumps as far as you can. Meaning you will use more fuel per jump, but jump a lot less.

If the path lines that appear are solid, you can make the jump without fueling or scooping. Eventually the path line might appear dotted. This means you will need to refuel or scoop before you will be able to actually make that jump.

Comment: Note: By nature, this should generally cause the economical route to also be the route most likely to offer frequent (or, at least, frequent enough) scooping opportunities. No guarantees, though.